Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos' centos 9
The network is working fine and ping with even mirrors.centos.org is working. but using yum has errors like this mentioned below and
also DNS sets to 8.8.8.8.
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'baseos':
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-9-stream&arch=x86_64&protocol=https,http 
[Failed to connect to mirrors.centos.org port 443: Connection refused]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': Cannot prepare internal 

mirrorlist: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-9-stream&arch=x86_64&protocol=https,http 
[Failed to connect to mirrors.centos.org port 443: Connection refused]


have you tried to use a browser for these URLs? if I click on it it works. so my assumption is that it may a local issue on your side like a firewall rule or similar

Is a proxy server configured (or missing) for yum?

turns out that was an blocked access by fedora repository. ..
